# Change Xml Declaration, or select xml without declaration section

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I need to change the xml declaration section of by document, or just select the data minus the declaration. Which is easier?

This is an example of what my xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master page-height="11in" page-width="8.5in" margin-top="0.50in" margin-left="0.8in" margin-right="0.8in" margin-bottom="0.25in" master-name="PageMaster">
            <fo:region-body border-style="none" border-width="thin" margin-top="0in" margin-left="0in" margin-right="0in" margin-bottom="0.25in"/>
            <fo:region-after border-style="none" border-width="thin" extent="0.25in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="PageMaster"/>
</fo:root>
```

I'm trying to change the xml declaration to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

Comment: it works... Try adding one more <Key-Enter>.

Comment: Please, add more formatting...

Comment: *Why* are you trying to change the XML declaration?

Comment: How are you reading/writing this? XmlDocument? XmlReader? XDocument? What have you tried?

Comment: @Tomalak when our company switched to 64 bit servers, there are some characters (non-breaking space &#160;) that are printing weird characters on some of our documents. I contacted AntennaHouse support (we're using XslFormatter to generate our pdfs) and they found out that unless explicitly specified, those non-breaking spaces weren't encoded as ANSI and the 64bit supposedly doesn't recognize that. We opened our xml file in Notepad++, selected the "Convert To ANSI" and then it started working. The support guy said, just encode your document as ISO-8859-1 and everything will work.

Comment: @RobLevine it's getting passed as an xml string, then create an xml document from that. I tried doing xml.SelectSingleNode, but it tells me "Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function."

Comment: Changing the XML declaration won't magically change the encoding of the document. *To be clear: what you are trying to do wont help you.* Fix the process that creates the XML documents instead of hacking around in its results. Also: 64bit servers or not has *nothing at all* to do with the issue. You are missing basic knowledge about character encodings and should read up on that topic before you start applying any half-baked fixes.

Comment: To expand a little bit: I suspect your XML documents are broken to begin with, and the AntennaHouse support person was lying to you. Non-breaking spaces work in any character encoding - in UTF-16 just as well as in Windows-1252 (you shouldn't use ISO-8859-1, but that's a different point). You should start here: Open your XML files in a Hex editor and find out the byte sequences those characters use that don't work. This will help to determine what's wrong with the document.

Comment: @Tomalak I know the actual support person didn't know the answer, he said one of the Developers there told him that. We tested taking the original document, and printing. Then take that same document, change the encoding in Notepad++, save it, and print that, and it worked. Then after confirming that, he said to just change the declaration to the iso...I'll look at all of that that you said (hex) and see how much I can find out/learn. As far as changing all of our processes that create these documents, these are generated from xsl templates.

Comment: @Tomalak Is it as easy as just specifying some kind of declaration in that? Because these xslfo "blobs" are saved in the database without the xml declaration line, it just starts with &lt;fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"&gt;

Comment: If the documents are generated by XSL templates, you should not be having any encoding issues at all. For the non-breaking space, you should see byte sequence `00 A0` for UTF-16, `C2 A0` for UTF-8 and just `A0` for ANSI encoding, respectively. Check out other characters outside of the ASCII range as well - for consistency checking. To find our the character encoding of the BLOBs, check your database. How are these blobs integrated into the result documents?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you trying to change the XML programmatically? If so you can do so by creating new `XmlDeclaration` and replacing it with the previous one as shown below:

```
XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration;
xmlDeclaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "iso-8859-1", null);
doc.ReplaceChild(xmlDeclaration, doc.FirstChild);
```

You just have to make sure that the first child of the document is Xml Declaration.

Answer (score 1):

**The wanted "change of XML declaration" can be done very easily** (not commenting whether or not this change is the correct solution to your problem) using XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Just apply this transformation to the provided XML document**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master page-height="11in" page-width="8.5in" margin-top="0.50in" margin-left="0.8in" margin-right="0.8in" margin-bottom="0.25in" master-name="PageMaster">
            <fo:region-body border-style="none" border-width="thin" margin-top="0in" margin-left="0in" margin-right="0in" margin-bottom="0.25in"/>
            <fo:region-after border-style="none" border-width="thin" extent="0.25in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="PageMaster"/>
</fo:root>
```

**and the wanted result is produced**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master page-height="11in" page-width="8.5in" margin-top="0.50in" margin-left="0.8in" margin-right="0.8in" margin-bottom="0.25in" master-name="PageMaster">
            <fo:region-body border-style="none" border-width="thin" margin-top="0in" margin-left="0in" margin-right="0in" margin-bottom="0.25in" />
            <fo:region-after border-style="none" border-width="thin" extent="0.25in" />
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="PageMaster" />
```